# Memory Leak in Chrome: What are blink roots?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, memory-leaks

I'm doing some memory leak bug fixing in an angular 9 application. I have a situation where some Components are leaking but I don't find the GC Root. I have no idea why the Elements are still in the heap.

What are these Blink roots?

[image]

- Console is clear
- I'm in inkognito mode
- I ran the GC

I already read that there is a leak in chrome when using password inputs, but i have no forms at all on this pages.

What could be the reason?

Thanks

Comment: Active Subscriptions, that have a binding to a html Element, that are not properly unsubscribed on NgDestroy or maybe Viewchilden? 
Maybe show some code of the component, what you are suspect of "Memory Leaking"

Comment: I have the strong opinion that my problem has something to do with angular/animations

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is caused by the [undo stack not being cleared in your input fields](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=961494).

It is a small Chrome memory memory leak that becomes huge because of the new `__ngContext__` feature.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and so we normally are using the `requestIdleCallback` to directly clear `__ngContext__` to solve the memory leak in our project. This will diminish DOM memory leaks outside our control.

```
if ('requestIdleCallback' in window) {
  // Use requestIdleCallback to schedule work.
} else {
  // Do what you’d do today.
}
```